# Need to install dlib package in windows 7

Tags: python, dlib

I tried to install dlib package in windows 7 using the below commands,

```
pip install dlib==19.18.0
```

and

```
python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz#sha256=8ca127253a0ca82a3d847148515f82ff2c504ed77a6385ec4f38c7f8e5360860
```

Download tar file and run python *setup.py* install.

I am getting the below error:

```
Collecting dlib==19.18.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/62/aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28/dlib-19.18.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\admin\envs\api\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\setu
p.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\
n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5sltbyhe' --python-tag cp36
       cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\dlib\
  Complete output (55 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8h
c1\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\admin\envs\api\scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8hc
1\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-hwgs8hc1/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "c:\users\admin\envs\api\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\admin\envs\api\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Admin\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\admin\\envs\\api\\scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEAS
E=C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\envs\api\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
p\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hwgs8hc1\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fil
e__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3bbuo3ir\ins
tall-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\admin\envs\api\include\site\python3.6\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I need to install dlib version==19.18.0 or 19.19.0.
I am using python 3.6.5 and pycharm. I need to install dlib without using anaconda.
Please help me with this...

Comment: first, install

pip install cmake
then

pip install dlib==19.18.0

Comment: CMake installed, but the issue does not fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

Via Anaconda we can install the dlib.

1. Install the anaconda exe file from this link 
   (https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section)
2. In Conda prompt, create an environment using this command

   ```
   **conda create --name env_name python=3.7.0**
   ```
3. Then activate the env

   ```
    **conda activate env_nam**e
   ```
4. Install dlib

   ```
    **conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17**
   ```